# CSS - absolute positioning issue

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

[image]

I would like to understand why the **list** of the **Dropdown** menu is not adjusted to the left-bottom edge of the navigation item correctly.

(I have already tried to add `left: 0px` to `.dropdown-menu` which worked properly for the horizontal gap, but i do not have idea how to deal with the vertical.)

```css
.navbar {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #252525;
  font-size: 0;
  /* to remove white-space gap between child blocks */
}

.navitem {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  /* root eM*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navitem:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  /*left:0px;*/
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navitem link">Link1</li>
  <li class="navitem link">Link2</li>
  <li class="navitem link">Link3</li>
  <li class="navitem dropdown">
    <div>Dropdown</div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `top: 100%;` which will make the **dropdown-menu** start at the bottom of the **dropdown**.

And add `right: 0;` or `left:0;` to make it start from either sides of the **dropdown**.

**See code snippet:**

```css
.navbar {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #252525;
  font-size: 0;
  /* to remove white-space gap between child blocks */
}

.navitem {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  /* root eM*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navitem:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  /*left:0px;*/
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #252525;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navitem link">Link1</li>
  <li class="navitem link">Link2</li>
  <li class="navitem link">Link3</li>
  <li class="navitem dropdown">
    <div>Dropdown</div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```